# what are the stylised characters often seen in social media posts?

Tags: html, unicode

Many posts and pages on social media often make use of uncommon stylised lettering to give a humorous effect or otherwise be eye-catching such as:

`<div id="..." class="...">
    <p>LIKE THE ACKUP JUST INCASE WE GET PERMANENTLY ZUCCED </p>
<p>`

and this:

`<a>Ｖａｐｏｒｗａｖｅ</a>`

What exactly are the "" and "Ｖ" type characters and what are their purposes? Wouldnt using normal text characters make these redundant?

Edit:
adding an image of the code for those who may not be able to see the characters:
[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. It appears like you posted the characters (whatever those were...) in a way that corrupted them, most likely in an encoding that is _not_ the standard UTF-8 as used today.

Comment: They appear to display fine in chrome browser. perhaps a screen image will help you see it

Comment: I am using a chromium browser, I do _not_ see something that makes sense. Remember that what you see also depends on what character fonts you have installed locally.

Comment: That is correct but in this case, i have seen these characters on browsers on different machines

Comment: I see what you mean on the image you posted. That differs from the text you posted for me. Well, I'd say you already perfectly nailed the purpose or motivation behind that: eye-catching. It is a question of personal preference and expression, I'd say. No right or wrong there...

Comment: I suppose my question is more the actual official intent of these characters. My initial thoughts are that they where simply added for "style" purposes to make console applications look more appealing but i could be wrong. Ps thanks for your assistance

Comment: That might also be an attempt to "mark" posts to "prove" later that they have been cited or copied blindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is Unicode codepoint [`U+1F171 SQUARED LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F171/index.htm).  It is defined in the [Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F100.pdf) section of the Unicode standard.

From [this Wikipedia explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_Alphanumerics):

> **Enclosed alphanumerics** is a Unicode block of typographical symbols of an alphanumeric within a circle, a bracket or other not-closed enclosure, or ending in a full stop. There is another block for these characters (U+1F100—U+1F1FF), encoded in the Supplementary Multilingual Plane, which contains the set of Regional Indicator Symbols as of Unicode 6.0.
>
> ---
>
> ### Purpose
>
> Many of these characters were originally intended for use as bullets for lists.<sup>[3]</sup> The parenthesized forms are historically based on typewriter approximations of the circled versions.<sup>[3]</sup> Although these roles have been supplanted by styles and other markup in "rich text" contexts, the characters are included in the Unicode standard "for interoperability with the legacy East Asian character sets and for the occasional text context where such symbols otherwise occur."<sup>[3]</sup> The Unicode Standard considers these characters to be distinct from characters which are similar in form but specialized in purpose, such as the circled C, P or R characters which are defined as copyright and trademark symbols or the circled a used for an at sign.<sup>[3]</sup>

`Ｖ` is Unicode codepoint [`U+FF36 FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER V`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FF36/index.htm).  It is defined in the [Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFF00.pdf) section of the Unicode standard.

From [this Wikipedia explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms):

> In CJK (Chinese, Japanese and Korean) computing, graphic characters are traditionally classed into fullwidth (in Taiwan and Hong Kong: 全形; in CJK and Japanese: 全角) and halfwidth (in Taiwan and Hong Kong: 半形; in CJK and Japanese: 半角) characters. With fixed-width fonts, a halfwidth character occupies half the width of a fullwidth character, hence the name.
>
> In the days of computer terminals and text mode computing, characters were normally laid out in a grid, often 80 columns by 24 or 25 lines. Each character was displayed as a small dot matrix, often about 8 pixels wide, and an SBCS (single byte character set) was generally used to encode characters of western languages.
>
> For a number of practical and aesthetic reasons, Han characters would need to be twice as wide as these fixed-width SBCS characters. These "fullwidth characters" were typically encoded in a DBCS (double byte character set), although less common systems used other variable-width character sets that used more bytes per character.
>
> Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms is also the name of a Unicode block U+FF00–FFEF.
>
> ---
>
> ### In Unicode
>
> In Unicode, if a certain grapheme can be represented as either a fullwidth character or a halfwidth character, it is said to have both a fullwidth form and a halfwidth form.
>
> Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms is the name of Unicode block U+FF00–FFEF, the last of the Basic Multilingual Plane excepting the short Specials block at U+FFF0–FFFF.
>
> Range U+FF01–FF5E reproduces the characters of ASCII 21 to 7E as fullwidth forms, that is, a fixed width form used in CJK computing. This is useful for typesetting Latin characters in a CJK environment. U+FF00 does not correspond to a fullwidth ASCII 20 (space character), since that role is already fulfilled by U+3000 "ideographic space."
>
> Range U+FF65–FFDC encodes halfwidth forms of Katakana and Hangul characters – see half-width kana. Range U+FFE0–FFEE includes fullwidth and halfwidth symbols.